# Django No module named 'src' при переходе к другому приложению

Tags: python, django, redirect

Сделал отдельное приложение для авторизации пользователя. После авторизации хочу отправить его в другое приложение. Делаю это так:

```
return reverse('/accountant');
```

или

```
return reverse('/balance');
```

или

```
return reverse('accountant:balance');
```

или

```
return redirect("/accountant");
```

На что получаю ошибку:
[image: Ошибка]

Что я делаю не так, и как это делать так?

Для приложения accountant urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.balance, name='balance'),
    url(r'^account/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.account_edit, name='account_edit'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.category_view, name='category_view'),
]
```

для приложения auth_page:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', views.auth_page, name='auth_page'),
]
```

для всего сайта:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accountant/', include('accountant.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('auth_page.urls')),
]
```

Switch to copy-and-paste view:

```
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accountant

Django Version: 1.9.8
Python Version: 3.5.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'accountant',
 'auth_page']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  149.response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Rail\Documents\Django\Assistant\auth_page\views.py" in auth_page
  25.             return reverse("/accountant");

File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  600.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))

File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  508.                              (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /accountant
Exception Value: Reverse for '/accountant' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Исправил urls.py для всего сайта и получил:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accountant/', include('accountant.urls')),
    url(r'^$', include('auth_page.urls')),
]
```

[image: Новая ошибка]

Comment: 1) Я пока не понял, что это за ошибка, но на всякий случай можно `urls.py` обоих приложений (из которого переходим и в которое переходим, несущественное можно убрать)? / 2) Можно «Switch to copy-and-paste view» и полный Traceback сюда? (через правку вопроса)

Comment: python manage.py check что показывает?

Comment: WARNINGS:
?: (urls.W001) Your URL pattern '^$' uses include with a regex ending with a '$'
. Remove the dollar from the regex to avoid problems including URLs.

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
После удаления $ говорит: System check identified no issues (0 silenced).